# How to run a function in background without blocking main thread and serving flask app

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I have read through multiple SO answers regarding asyncio to figure out how to accomplish this. However, the answers that i found didn't work for the problem i'm having.

I have a flask app that I want to serve while running a background function. I have the following code:

```
import asyncio
import time
from flask import Flask

def background_task():
    while True:
        print('hej')
        time.sleep(1)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, world'

asyncio.run(background_task())

app.run()

print('running')
```

I want background_task to keep running while serving the app. But currently asyncio.run blocks the main thread. How do i make it so that the background_task is run as a coroutine?

Comment: Do you need to run `background_task` as part of the same process as Flask? Why not just run it separately?

Comment: Yes. It's going to be a self contained microservice, where the background task will update the database of the service.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `threading` module instead, I've found it useful, here's an example:

```py
import threading
import asyncio
import time
from flask import Flask

def background_task():
    while True:
        print('hej')
        time.sleep(1)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, world'

#We start a thread instead of using asyncio...
t=threading.Thread(target=background_task)
t.start()

app.run()

print('running')
```

And here's a tutorial: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried your code - but the print('hej') runs twice every second? If i ctrl + c in my terminal, it seems that i exit a process, and the app keeps running but then it only prints once every second.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the development server which, I believe, starts two processes, one of which restarts the other upon changes. Because you thread starts when your code is imported, you'll end up with two threads running. You probably want to use something like `@app.before_first_request` to run your thread. You'll probably want something similar to stop it.

Comment: @MikeHawkins you should check dirn's comment.